# Can anyone recomment a good tweet and tweetdeck type combo for an *intranet*

Tags: twitter, intranet

I love twitter (for microblogging) and I love tweetdeck (for nice notifications)

So much so I want to try something similar for a company intranet so people can bounce ideas and questions to and fro.

I've seen a few microblogging engines around, but is there anything which goes nicely with a notification app for windows?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used yammer before and it was very good for internal work - it can open up rss feeds with specific versions

https://www.yammer.com/about/product

Comment: if you like the answer then please mark it as accepted so that others know it is answered - thanks